# SSIS create SSISDB catalog certificate error

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2017

I am trying to create SSISDB catalog to publish my SSIS packages. While I am following the steps needed to create the catalog I am stuck with this weird error, I googled but I did not found any satisfying answer to this issue. I am getting the following error. I am working on SQL server 2017. Do anyone has encountered such error. Really appreciate the solution.

[image: Error message SSISDB creating]

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://www.fourmoo.com/2013/05/17/sql-server-2012-integration-services-error-creating-catalog-database/) blog?

Comment: Try granting complete folder access to SQL Server service account or add as system administrator.